# XAML - How can I use a KeyBinding command to go to a new line in the textbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, newline

I am simply trying to move to a new line when Return + Shift are pressed.

I got this much from a previous post on here:

```
<TextBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Key="Return" Modifiers="Shift" Command=" " />
</TextBox.InputBindings>
```

But I cannot find anywhere that explains how to accomplish the move to a new line within the textbox.

I cannot use the: AcceptsReturn="True" as I want return to trigger a button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a nice way to do it without using an ICommand.

Simply added this PreviewKeyDown event onto the  control in xaml:

```
PreviewKeyDown="MessageText_PreviewKeyDown"
```

And this is the C# behind:

```
private void MessageText_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the textbox
        var textbox = sender as TextBox;

        // Check if we have pressed enter
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter && Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift))
        {
            // Add a new line where cursor is
            var index = textbox.CaretIndex;

            // Insert a new line
            textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Insert(index, Environment.NewLine);

            // Shift the caret forward to the newline
            textbox.CaretIndex = index + Environment.NewLine.Length;

            // Mark this key as handled by us
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an `ICommand` defined, you can attach a handler for the `UIElement.PreviewKeyUp` event to the `TextBox`. Otherwise you will have to define an `ICommand` implementation and assign it to the `KeyBinding.Command` so that the `KeyBinding` can actually execute. Either solution finally executes the same logic to add the linebreak.

You then use the `TextBox.AppendText` method to append a linebreak and the `TextBox.CaretIndex` property to move the caret to the end of the new line.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <TextBox PreviewKeyUp="TextBox_PreviewKeyUp" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private void TextBox_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)    
  {
    if (!e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter) 
      || !e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift))
    {
      return;
    }

    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    textBox.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    textBox.CaretIndex = textBox.Text.Length;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's about as simple as I imagined it was going to be. I figured I'd have to go the event route, but it's not bad, considering. Wasn't sure if there was some nice simple way in XAML I didn't know about. I think I should be OK with the ICommand on the box, the only one that I'll be adding should be the send button beside it. Thanks again.

Comment: You need C# to solve your problem. There is no XAML only solution.